# Is socket.io .emit() method sync or async operation?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have server side code which runs in a loop like this:

```
        var start = Date.now();
        var lotsOfData = calculateData();//SYNCHRONOS, returns 500kb of data
        var end = Date.now();

        console.log('got data in ', end-start, ' ms'); // ~40ms

        var substart = Date.now();
        req.io.emit('lotsOfData', lotsOfData);// IS IT SYNC OR ASYNC ?
        var subend = Date.now();

        console.log('emitted data in ', subend-substart, ' ms'); // ~40ms
```

At first I'm doing pretty expensive calculations to get some data. It's synchronous operation and code gets blocked there. After that, I'm emiting and event and sending this data with it.

My test shows that both getting and sending takes ~40ms. However, if the sending part was asynchronous, it would be possible to get the next portion of data while sending the current one, therefore server would send portions of data each 40 miliseconds, not each 80 miliseconds like now.

Hopefuly you get what I mean. Is it possible to speed it up?

Comment: It depends on what your calculateData is doing. If you can make `calculateData()` async and implement [Streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) , you can make it work with socket.io, because it also [support NodeJS Streams](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#socket.io-stream) . By doing this you will for sure you will have faster response.

Comment: Start with using `process.hrtime` instead of `Date.now`, to make sure you're getting correct timings.